# Moving Mosquitto broker to new server

Tags: migration, production, mqtt, mosquitto

We are in a process to move the Production server to new one.As we are already using Mosquitto Broker installed in the current server, will all the subscriptions remains same when we move the Broker to new server ?

The New Server IP will be remains same as current server.

What are the challanges comes in this migration and how to overcome for MQTT Broker.

Look forward for valueble solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have persistence enabled, the broker stores any retained messages as well as subscriptions and queued messages for durable clients. The file, normally called `mosquitto.db`, where these are stored is located according to how you set the configuration `persistence_location` option.

The file can be safely copied to a new machine. The internal db ids that are 64 bit wide are read/written using the endian of the machine, so if you swap endian they will change their value, but consistently across the whole file so it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Hello, I have done above procedure by replacing old database file after installing MQTT again. But my old file is getting overwrite with the new database file when i start MQTT.

Comment: That should only happen after it has been reloaded though.

Comment: Can you please explain briefly?                                           1. mosquitto.db created for my MQTT instance.                          2. I have taken the backup and reinstall the MQTT again                3. When i run the MQTT new mosquitto.db created                        4. I tried to replace the db file with my earlier backup db file      5. When start connecting to MQTT, db file again become 6kb so my backup db file is overwriting .

Comment: Start mosquitto. Stop mosquitto. You should have a new mosquitto.db. On the new host, ensure that mosquitto isn't running. Copy mosquitto.db to the appropriate location and then start mosquitto.

Comment: Moving mosquitto.db from a Raspberry Pi to an x86_64 machine both using the same version: 1.5.7 resulted in:
"Warning: Unsupported chunk "18" in persistent database file. Ignoring."
And the persistent data being lost.

Answer (score 3):

Basically when you turn the old server off the client connections will all drop. How the clients reconnect to the new server will depend on the logic in your clients, but they will need to reconnect and resubscribe to the topics they are interested in.

Since it is a new instance of mosquitto there will be no retained topic data on the new instance.

Comment: If this server is migrated to one of the same architecture, and you migrate Mosquitto's database with it, then retained topics should still be there. (I'm not sure whether the database is architecture-dependent.)

Comment: How can we move the database to the new server? As we installed the broker as a windows service, can we copy the files directly in to the new server and configure in such a way that all topics will remain same.